# Failed to activate virtualenv via shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv, fish, pyenv

I'm trying to activate my pyenv-virtualenv environment through very simple bash script like this.

```
set -e
pyenv activate myenv
```

But I can't activate my env with below error:

```
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

I can activate it in command line, so I think it's due to my shell environment.

I use `fish shell`, but it's launched after `$PATH` settings read in `bash shell`.
I show you my settings.

`.bash_profile`:

```
export LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"

export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"

export PATH="/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"

exec fish
```

And my `config.fish`:

```
status --is-interactive; and source (pyenv init -|psub)
status --is-interactive; and source (pyenv virtualenv-init -|psub)
```

What's wrong?

I'm using:

- `OS`: OS X 10.13.5
- `fish`: v2.7.1
- `pyenv`: v1.2.5
- `pyenv-virtualenv`: v1.1.3

Comment: Does the script work under Bash?

Comment: No, it also doesn't work under Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the cause is that you are *initializing* PyEnv in the Fish shell environment but then *calling* PyEnv in the Bash shell environment (via your Bash script). To solve this problem, you could try either of the following potential solutions:

1. Initialize PyEnv in your Bash environment (in addition to your Fish environment)
2. Write your script in Fish instead of Bash

Since PyEnv seems so have better support for Bash than Fish, let's focus on option #1. Step 3 of the PyEnv installation guide suggests the following command for adding PyEnv initialization to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After running that command, I suspect your script will function as you expect. If it does not, you could try adding the same PyEnv initialization snippet (that you just added to your `~/.bash_profile`) to the top of your Bash script.